# MongoDB dot notation only filters in deep nested array, doesnt actually do CRUD

Tags: json, mongodb

In a MongoDB collection all documents follow a structure like this:

```json
[
  {
    ....
    children: {
      ....
      children: {
        ....
        children: {
          ....
          children: [
            {
              ....
              children: [Array],
              ....
            }
          ],
          ....
        },
        ....
      },
      ....
    },
    ....
  }
]
```

If I want do a filter like this:

```json
{"children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.children.0.id":"64be542c3df044baed992413_30"}
```

I actually can. It will return me the document where the specified children's id is equal to id that I specified.

Problem is, it only filters.

In find, it will return the root and whole document, not just the children I specified.

In update, it will update the root document, not the children I specified.

In delete, it will update root and every nested document within it, not the children and the children of it.

Only insert works, which, not surpising.

What can I do about this?

I cannot

- Switch DB
- Change Data Structure